# Converting this drawing into Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I tried to create the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\fill [mycolor] (0,0) rectangle (10,5.5);
\node at (0,-0.3) (A) {};
\node at (10,-0.3) (B) {};
\draw[->] (A.south) to[out=-20,in=-160] (B.south);

\node at (-0.2,0) (A2) {};
\node at (-0.2,5.5) (C) {};
\draw[->] (A2.west) to[out=140,in=-140] (C.west);

\node at (0,5.7) (C2) {};
\node at (10.2,0) (D) {};
\node at (11,6) (E) {};
\draw[->] (C.north) to[out=90,in=120] (E.south) to[out=270,in=0] (D.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But the arrows don't work as I want and I am simply not handy with Tikz..
Could someone recreate my drawing into Tikz please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One option: the arrows for `S_{1}` and `S_{2}` can be obtained with `bend`; the arrow labeled `R` can be obtained with the `out=`, `in=` syntax plus `looseness`:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\colorlet{mycolor}{gray!10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,>=latex]
\path
  coordinate (ll) at (0,0)
  coordinate (ur) at (10,5.5)
  coordinate (lr) at (ur|-ll)
  coordinate (ul) at (ll|-ur);
\filldraw[mycolor,draw=black]
  (ll) rectangle (ur);
\foreach \Name in {ll,ur,lr,ul}
  \node[inner sep=2pt,fill,circle] at (\Name) {};    
\draw[dashed]
  ([yshift=-15pt]{$ (ll)!0.5!(lr) $}) -- ([yshift=15pt]{$ (ul)!0.5!(ur) $})
  ([xshift=-15pt]{$ (ul)!0.5!(ll) $}) -- ([xshift=15pt]{$ (ur)!0.5!(lr) $});        
\draw[->]
  ([xshift=-20pt]ll) to[bend left] node[left] {$S_{2}$} ([xshift=-20pt]ul);
\draw[->]
  ([yshift=-20pt]ll) to[bend right] node[below] {$S_{1}$} ([yshift=-20pt]lr);
\draw[->,overlay]
  ([yshift=20pt]ul) to[out=30,in=60,looseness=2] node[above] {$R$} ([xshift=20pt]lr);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Another option in which the arrow labeled `R` was obtained with control points:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\colorlet{mycolor}{gray!10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,>=latex]
\path
  coordinate (ll) at (0,0)
  coordinate (ur) at (10,5.5)
  coordinate (lr) at (ur|-ll)
  coordinate (ul) at (ll|-ur);
\filldraw[mycolor,draw=black]
  (ll) rectangle (ur);
\foreach \Name in {ll,ur,lr,ul}
  \node[inner sep=2pt,fill,circle] at (\Name) {};    
\draw[dashed]
  ([yshift=-15pt]{$ (ll)!0.5!(lr) $}) -- ([yshift=15pt]{$ (ul)!0.5!(ur) $})
  ([xshift=-15pt]{$ (ul)!0.5!(ll) $}) -- ([xshift=15pt]{$ (ur)!0.5!(lr) $});        
\draw[->]
  ([xshift=-20pt]ll) to[bend left] node[left] {$S_{2}$} ([xshift=-20pt]ul);
\draw[->]
  ([yshift=-20pt]ll) to[bend right] node[below] {$S_{1}$} ([yshift=-20pt]lr);
\draw[->,overlay]
  ([yshift=20pt]ul) .. controls (3,10) and (16,10).. node[right=3pt,pos=0.7] {$R$} ([xshift=20pt]lr);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]